# What is the purpose of group privileges in sudoers file?

Tags: visudo

I removed my regular user from the sudoers file but it is still part of sudo group which has all privileges granted in the sudoers file. When I try to execute any command in sudo from my regular user it says that user is not listed in the sudoers. I was expecting that sudo commands would execute normally since the regular user is part of a group which is listed in the sudoers. My question is why do we specify permission of groups if we should also specify all individual users (in the sudoers) in order for them to execute commands with sudo?

Comment: Your expected behavior is indeed the default behavior AFAIK - without seeing your complete `sudoers` file and group memberships it's hard to know why that's not happening

Answer (score 1):

**The purpose of the group privileges in the sudoers file** is to conveniently be able to add or remove users from the /etc/sudo group for granting or removing `sudo` access.

**The default`/etc/sudoers` file** allows for the `sudo` group to execute `sudo` commands.  To bring this default back, you would have to modify your files back to the defaults.  Compare your `/etc/sudoers` file with this default file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The most likely culprit of your issue is highlighted in **bold**.

For this to work the `/etc/group` entry will also need to be formatted properly:

**The `sudo` entry in the `/etc/group` file:**

```
sudo:x:27:ljames,user1,user2
```